# Android ScrollView's scroll disable when set width & height programically

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I had the following structure in my Android application

```
LinearLayout
     ScrollView
          LinearLayout
           -- Elements ---
```

Then I need to set the width & height of the ScrollView programically. So I wrote the following code

```
ScrollView sv=(ScrollView)activity.findViewById(R.id.menuScroll);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams relp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,height-margin);
relp.setMargins(width, 0, 0, 0);
sv.setLayoutParams(relp);
```

But when I added the `setLayoutParams`, its scroll property. Can't scrolling the internal elements. Any idea ? I am new to android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use this for RelativeLayout:

```
 private ScrollView mScrollView;
 mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mScrollView.getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.leftMargin= width;
 layoutParams.setMargins(width, 0, 0, 0);
 mScrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This works for me. I think that's similar to LinearLayout.

Comment: thanks. but the ScrollView is in a LineatLayout not in a RelativeLayout. So the above code will work ?

Comment: **LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mScrollView.getLayoutParams(); layoutParams.setMargins(width, 0, 0, 0); mScrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);**